# How to Convert Date String into Different format?

Tags: php, date

I have a date that gets sent from a database which comes in a string format of '2018-01-01'. What I want to do is convert it into a string of month and year. E.G. 'January 2018'.

What would be the best way of doing so using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to turn your string into a timestamp and the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function with the `F Y` format to get what you want:

```
$date = "2018-01-01";
$formatted = date("F Y", strtotime($date));
```